# A question of the ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django-models

When I read the document of the Django model, a description that describes how to create a many-to-many relationship by the intermediary model attracted me.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

below is the quote for the part of the document.

> There are a few restrictions on the intermediate model:

> Your intermediate model must contain one - and only one - foreign key to the source > model (this would be Group in our example), or you must explicitly specify the foreign keys Django should use for the relationship using ManyToManyField.through_fields. If you have more than one foreign key and through_fields is not specified, a validation error will be raised. A similar restriction applies to the foreign key to the target model (this would be Person in our example).

> For a model which has a many-to-many relationship to itself through an intermediary model, two foreign keys to the same model are permitted, but they will be treated as the two (different) sides of the many-to-many relationship. If there are more than two foreign keys though, you must also specify through_fields as above, or a validation error will be raised.

I don't understand the description above:

1. what are the source model and target model?
2. Why can the intermediate model only contain one foreign key to the source or target?
3. How to use the through_fields to specify two foreign keys for the many-to-many relationship to itself?